# WCF Binding Issue with IIS for HTTPS versus HTTP A binding instance has already been associated to listen

Tags: wcf, iis, https

We have an issue in IIS when testing a WCF Service.  We have a service that with HTTP runs without issue, lets say on Port 8060 (example only).

When we added in IIS HTTPS on port 8553 (again example only) and associate to a certificate we have we get the error

> A binding instance has already been associated to listen URI
>   'http://:8060/.svc'. If two endpoints want
>   to share the same ListenUri, they must also share the same binding
>   object instance. The two conflicting endpoints were either specified
>   in AddServiceEndpoint() calls, in a config file, or a combination of
>   AddServiceEndpoint() and config.

The endpoint in the `Web.config` looks like:

```
<service name="<name of service>" behaviorConfiguration="DefaultBehaviorConfig">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="basicHTTPBindingConfig" contract="<interface name>">
    </endpoint>
 </service>
```

is it the `bindingConfiguration`?

Changing protocol binding to `wsHttpBinding`

HTTPS will open.

Answer (score 1):

This issue mainly stems that the service endpoint address has the same relative address. Please carefully check all the endpoints and keep all the endpoints from not having the same relative address, for example, the below configuration may cause this error.

```
<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mybinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
```

Please post the complete configuration file (System.Servicemodel section), I will give you an effective reply.
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.
**Updated.**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="WcfService1.Service1">
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="WcfService1.IService1" bindingConfiguration="https"></endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"></endpoint>
  </service>
</services>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="https">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

We could also simplify this configuration by using protocol mapping.

```
  <system.serviceModel>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="https">
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None"></transport>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
<protocolMapping>
  <add scheme="https" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="https"/>
  <add scheme="http" binding="basicHttpBinding"/>
</protocolMapping>
```

Comment: Hi Abraham, So what I am hearing is I'll need to have two endpoints, one for the HTTP and another one for the HTTPS.  Does that sound right?  If so that is fine, just a little surprised :).

Comment: Yes, when we enable https support for the WCF service, Not only we need to add the https base address but also we need to add an additional service endpoint that has transport security mode. Please refer to my updated reply.

Comment: Hi Abraham,  So all is working with most of the services now (Thank You).  There are a couple of services that do not work giving the same error and will not work using HTTP or HTTPS.  One observation is if we remove the HTTPS from IIS the HTTP works fine.  Otherwise we get the error.  I am using the same bindings as the one that works and issue still happening.  Wondering if it's something in the WCF itself.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Do you mean there are other services that don't work properly (even though they already use the above configuration)? Is the port occupied?